# Is it possible to use username without domain for authentication in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I just created tenant with name mycompany.com. Within this tenant, I registered  Service Provider with name SP.
After integrating my application with WSO2, the apps will create SAML Authn request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest  AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost:8443/myapp/auth/sso"
    Destination="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"
    ForceAuthn="false" ID="a2i70af753i64cce4ehj977h3h9085h"
    IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2016-03-30T02:51:12.083Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">SP@mycompany.com</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" SPNameQualifier="SP"/>
    <saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

It will redirect to WSO2 login page with this URL:

```
https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fsamlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=mycompany.com&sessionDataKey=22e974a4-1a42-4670-82f5-3538828d7d03&relyingParty=SP%40mycompany.com&type=samlsso&sp=SP&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=GoogleOIDCAuthenticator%3AGoogle%3BFacebookAuthenticator%3AFB%3BSAMLSSOAuthenticator%3AADFS%3BBasicAuthenticator%3ALOCAL
```

I am wondering why I need to passing tenant domain name as part of username.

i.e:

Username: user@mycompany.com

Passwword: secret

Can we configure WSO2 such that it takes the domain name from the URL parameter instead of appending it to the username

Answer (score 1):

Username is used in the same format throughtout all the cases. So, tenant domain should be there with username.

Comment: In authentication endpoint  we are already getting the tenant domain as a parameter.So as a workaround i am trying to append the username and the tenant domain and passing it for wso2 .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to append tenant domain to the username, you can use tenant dropdown feature in the authentication endpoint as described in 'Loading tenants into the dropdown in the login page of the authentication endpoint web application' section of [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Customizing+the+Authentication+Endpoint

Comment: That is one way.But for security reason we do not want user to know all our tenants

Answer (score 1):

If you have single tenant better you don't want use tenant like above. Please use WSO2 IS without tenant. So you can use only username and password.

Comment: Yes.But we are trying this for a multi tenant application.