# How to let users login using their email address?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using `WSO2IS-5.6.0`. I have configured a Service Provider and configured OAuth2 Inbound Authentication for that SP. I am using the Resident Identity Provider of the WSO2 with User Self Registration enabled.

By default, WSO2IS asks `username` and `password` to let the user login, where username is of format `<actual_username>@<tenant_domain>`.

But, I want to configure the WSO2IS such that it asks for `email` of the user ( which is taken during the user registration ) rather than `username`.

I followed the guide from [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username). But for a tenant, it leads to weird format of email such as `<email>@<tenant_domain>`. So for example, If registered email address is `johndoe@foo.com` and the tenant domain is `bar.com`, the user will have to enter `johndoe@foo.com@bar.com` as username, which I certainly don't want.

Is there a way I can configure WSO2IS to let user login using JUST the email address? ( In continuation of the example, just using `johndoe@foo.com` and not `johndoe@foo.com@bar.com` )

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/60494075

Comment: @gusto2 Not helpful. The link you shared has the same content as that of the link of documentation I linked. Scroll down to the end of the page, and you will see the note: *With these configuration users can login to super tenant with both email user name (bob@gmal.com) or non email user names (alice). But for tenant only email user names allowed (tod@gmail.com@wso2.com)*

Answer (score 1):

When you have tenants that is the default behavior. If you don't wanna provide the tenant name, I guess you have to use tenant dropdown feature as mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Customizing+the+Authentication+Endpoint) you can also refer to [Is it possible to use username without domain for authentication in WSO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322798/is-it-possible-to-use-username-without-domain-for-authentication-in-wso2)